# Understanding a statement regarding dot products

Tags: linear-algebra

If $v\cdot w= 0$ (the dot product of vectors $v$ and $w$), then the zero vector $v$ is perpendicular to every $w$ because $v\cdot w = 0$.

I'm confused as to what every $w$ means. Does it mean $w$ and all its combinations (a line) or any $w$ that multiplied by $v$ which gives $0$.

Comment: it is confusing, can you rephrase ?

Comment: What you have is $v\cdot w=0$ then the vector $v$ is perpendicular to the vector $w$.

Comment: The first sentence is not a well-posed mathematical statement. (For instance, what are the $v$ and $w$?) If you are confused by some sentences in your textbook or notes, it would be better if you could quote them directly.

Answer (score 2):

> If the dot product between two vectors v and w = 0 then the zero vector v is perpendicular to every w because v w = 0.

This statement isn't phrased very well.  Assuming $\mathbf v$ is supposed to represent the zero vector, then we can instead say this:

> The zero vector $\mathbf v$ is perpendicular to every vector $\mathbf w$ because $\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf w = 0$ for all vectors $\mathbf w$.

That's perhaps not the most ideal improvement, but it's an improvement which preserves the original wording enough so that your question still makes sense.  In this case, "every vector" really does mean every possible vector.  It's basically a more verbose way of saying this:

> Every vector is perpendicular to the zero vector.

I should note that everything I said above assumes that the vectors all have the same dimension (i.e., same number of elements).

Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Thank you, this is what is I was asking, I phrased it incorrectly. Could you share how that's even possible though? I get that its anything multiplied by 0 is 0 but I don't see the geometry of it.

Comment: @JohnSmith, it wasn't incorrect (apart from the missing $\cdot$ in between the v and w near the end, technically), just slightly plump in the wording.  Unfortunately the geometry of perpendicularity with the 0 vector isn't the most intuitive, since the 0 vector is basically just a point (a vector of length zero).  Vectors in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{R}^3$ tell us only two things: magnitude and direction.  But we say the 0 vector has "arbitrary" direction since it's just a single point.  As for it being perpendicular to all other vectors, it's basically because "perpendicular" means

Comment: @JohnSmith "dot product is zero" and the dot product of any vector with the zero vector is zero. So if we were to draw a picture of the zero vector and any other vector, we wouldn't really look and go "aha, those are clearly perpendicular." It's more or less a convention that follows from the definition of perpendicularity. If we instead defined "perpendicular" to be "dot product equals 1" then the zero vector would be perpendicular to no vectors at all (and we'd have a bunch of other wacky antics ensuing). See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3679/307169) for more info, maybe it'll help

Answer (score 0):

Every $w$ which gives $v \cdot w = 0$, I'd assume.

Comment: Which is every vector.

Comment: The statement is a little confusing. If $v$ is the zero vector then $v \cdot w \forall w$ is trivial...

Answer (score 0):

Every $w$ means every vector $w$. You can easily see that for any vector $w$, if $v$ is a vector, than $v\cdot w=0$. Hence, they are perpendicular.